# decrypting and reading out

Tags: c#, excel, vba, encryption

I have a very simple application written in VBA (EXCEL). This application gets some input data and provides a `*.pro` file. (This app get input data and put them into `*.pro` file with its own format.)
The input fields are numeric and text data like:
 
CPE,W,W,15.8, 16.5, 12, 23, 143.23 and so on.
When I open the output in Notepad++, I see something like this:
[image]

I try to write a function with C#.NET that provides the similar output. So I investigate the **vba** file and found that it uses a binary file and write data to it by using [PUT statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266212(v=vs.60).aspx):

```
Open FileName For Binary Access Read Write Lock Write As #fn
Put #fn, 1&, DummyName
```

I write my code in C# and try to do it by using BinaryWritter. But the output of my code and **vba** app are NOT similar. Note that the *.pro file may be imported in some third party softwares like [CSi](http://www.csiamerica.com/) softwares. And as is clear, the output of my function is NOT importable. Here is a part of the code that I use:

```
    if (save.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        if (save.FileName.Length > 0)
            using (BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(save.FileName, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                br.Write(dummy + dummy + dummy + dummy);
                br.Write(7);
                br.Write(5);
                br.Write(1);
                br.Write(dummy + dummy + dummy + dummy + dummy + dummy + "01234567");
                br.Flush();
                br.Close();
            }
```

Is there a way to know which algorithm was used to create this output? Or is it possible to translate this output to a readable format?

Comment: The only reliable way to get it right is to port your VBA program to C#. Trying to reverse engineer it by examining the output file is a very slow, painful, and error-prone way to go about it.

Comment: The `Put` statement in VBA sometimes writes various descriptors and field lengths along with the data.  This additional information depends on the data type of the variable being written (i.e. `DummyName` in your case).  [This page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266212(v=vs.60).aspx) has the details.

Answer (score 0):

And this code to reading pro files

```js
Function FileReadOld() As Boolean
  
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim fn As Long
  Dim tmpBool As Boolean
  Dim tmpFileName As String
  Dim Dummy40 As String * 40
  Dim tmpSingle As Single
  
  FileReadOld = False

  On Error GoTo OpenFileError

  fn = FreeFile
  Close #fn
  Open FileName For Binary Access Read Write Lock Write As #fn

  Get #fn, 1&, DummyName
  Get #fn, , OldVersion
  Get #fn, , OldUnits
  Get #fn, , NumberOldSectionDatas
  Get #fn, , DummyString1
  
  If OldVersionRead = 6 And OldVersion <> 6 Then
    msg = "The file named " & FileName & " is not recognized as a "
    msg = msg & "PROPER Version 6 file.  The section database file was NOT "
    msg = msg & "read." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    LogMsg = LogMsg & msg
    Close #fn
    Exit Function
  End If
  
  If OldVersionRead = 7 And OldVersion <> 7 Then
    msg = "The file named " & FileName & " is not recognized as a "
    msg = msg & "PROPER Version 7 file.  The section database file was NOT "
    msg = msg & "read." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    LogMsg = LogMsg & msg
    Close #fn
    Exit Function
  End If
  
  Select Case OldUnits
    Case 1
      UnitsName = "Inches"
    Case 2
      UnitsName = "Feet"
    Case 3
      UnitsName = "Millimeters"
    Case 4
      UnitsName = "Meters"
    Case 5
      UnitsName = "Centimeters"
    Case Else
      msg = "The units specified in the file named " & FileName & " are "
      msg = msg & "not recognized.  The section database file was NOT "
      msg = msg & "read." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
      LogMsg = LogMsg & msg
      Close #fn
      Exit Function
  End Select
  
  
  If NumberOldSectionDatas > 0 Then
    ReDim SectionData(NumberOldSectionDatas)
  End If
  
  For i = 1 To NumberOldSectionDatas
  
    Get #fn, , Dummy40
    If OldVersionRead = 6 Then
      SectionData(i).Name = UCase$(RTrim$(Left$(Dummy40, 18&)))
    Else
      SectionData(i).Name = UCase$(RTrim$(Left$(Dummy40, 36&)))
    End If
    SectionData(i).shapetype = UCase$(Left$(Right$(Dummy40, 4&), 2&))

    Select Case SectionData(i).shapetype
      Case "I ":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_I
      Case "W ":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_I
      Case "WW":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_I
      Case "C ":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_CHANNEL
      Case "T ":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_T
      Case "TW":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_T
      Case "L ":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_ANGLE
      Case "2L":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_DBLANGLE
      Case "B ":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_BOX
      Case "P ":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_PIPE
      Case "R ":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_RECTANGULAR
      Case "CR":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_CIRCLE
      Case "G ":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_GENERAL
      Case "SD":   SectionData(i).sh = SECTION_GENERAL
    End Select

    '1: d, t3
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    Select Case SectionData(i).sh
      Case SECTION_I, SECTION_CHANNEL, SECTION_T, SECTION_ANGLE, SECTION_DBLANGLE
          SectionData(i).d = CDbl(tmpSingle)
      Case SECTION_BOX, SECTION_RECTANGULAR, SECTION_GENERAL
          SectionData(i).ht = CDbl(tmpSingle)
      Case SECTION_PIPE, SECTION_CIRCLE
          SectionData(i).od = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    End Select
    
    '2: bf, t2
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    Select Case SectionData(i).sh
      Case SECTION_I, SECTION_CHANNEL, SECTION_T
          SectionData(i).bf = CDbl(tmpSingle)
      Case SECTION_ANGLE, SECTION_DBLANGLE, SECTION_BOX, SECTION_RECTANGULAR, SECTION_GENERAL
          SectionData(i).b = CDbl(tmpSingle)
      Case SECTION_PIPE, SECTION_CIRCLE
          'not used
    End Select
    
    '3: tf
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    Select Case SectionData(i).sh
      Case SECTION_I, SECTION_CHANNEL, SECTION_T
          SectionData(i).bf = CDbl(tmpSingle)
      Case SECTION_ANGLE, SECTION_DBLANGLE, SECTION_BOX, SECTION_RECTANGULAR, _
           SECTION_GENERAL, SECTION_PIPE, SECTION_CIRCLE
          'not used
    End Select
    
    '4: tw
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    Select Case SectionData(i).sh
      Case SECTION_I, SECTION_CHANNEL, SECTION_T
          SectionData(i).twsdb = CDbl(tmpSingle)
      Case SECTION_ANGLE, SECTION_DBLANGLE, SECTION_PIPE
          SectionData(i).t = CDbl(tmpSingle)
      Case SECTION_BOX
          SectionData(i).tdes = CDbl(tmpSingle)
      Case SECTION_BOX, SECTION_RECTANGULAR, SECTION_GENERAL, SECTION_CIRCLE
          'not used
    End Select
    
    '5: xk
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    Select Case SectionData(i).sh
      Case SECTION_I, SECTION_CHANNEL, SECTION_T, SECTION_ANGLE, SECTION_DBLANGLE
          SectionData(i).kdes = CDbl(tmpSingle)
      Case SECTION_BOX, SECTION_RECTANGULAR, _
           SECTION_GENERAL, SECTION_PIPE, SECTION_CIRCLE
          'not used
    End Select
          
    '6: area
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).a = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '7: torsion
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).j = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '8: I33
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).ix = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '9: I22
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).iy = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '10: AS2
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).asy = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '11: AS3
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).asx = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '12: Z33
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).zx = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '13: Z22
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).zy = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '14: xb
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).x = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '15: yb
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).y = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '16: nothing
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    
    '17: dis
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    SectionData(i).dissdb = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '18: nothing
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    
    '19: t2b, nowhere to fill in this database
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    'SectionData(i).??? = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
    '20: tfb, nowhere to fill in this database
    Get #fn, , tmpSingle
    'SectionData(i).??? = CDbl(tmpSingle)
    
  Next i
  
  FileReadOld = True
  Close #fn
  
  Exit Function

OpenFileError:
  msg = "Can not open the file named " & FileName & "!  It may be in use "
  msg = msg & "by another program.  The section database file was NOT "
  msg = msg & "read." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
  LogMsg = LogMsg & msg
  Close #fn
  Exit Function

End Function
```